# Move camera based on Gameobjects Size

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

Can anybody share their experience on how to fit the Gameobject within the camera's view port/FOV by moving the camera without scaling the gameobject neither the camera. Here the point is I don want to change the scale of the object, I only want to move the camera.

Edit: I have added a box collider to the GO, Now How to fit the Collider to camera?

Regards,
Jithendrakumar.

Comment: I think your camera is `Perspective` ? Have you tried to code something, yet?

Comment: @dome12b , i have tried to move the camera to the bounds center of the object, now how to position it before the object so that it will cover the entire object in viewport??

Answer (score 1):

Below is the answer, i have found and working for all GO's regardless whatever the scaling is.
Here i have used cube as a test object with BoxCollider.

```
Camera.main.transform.position = Cube.transform.position + Cube.transform.forward * -(2 * Cube.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().bounds.size.y);
```